# git apply throws unrecognized input error on Linux Mint

Tags: git, config, linux-mint

Installed git through `sudo apt install git` on Linux Mint 20.2

`git --version` gives:

> git version 2.25.1

I'm having issues with applying modifications on mod.rs file of glutin through `git apply mod.rs`. It gives the following output:

> error: unrecognized input

After some troubleshooting, I found out that it could be related to color parameters and suggested solution indicates changing `[color] ui = always` to   `[color] ui = auto` on .gitconfig file.
The issue is that `git config --list --show-origin` does not output anything and `git config --global` only gives usage instructions starting with:

> usage: git config [<options>] ...

In case the following would be useful:
If I run `git diff` after making modifications on the mod.rs file, it gives all the correct output with colored lines.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `git config --global color.ui auto`

Comment: I followed @phd suggestion which created a new .gitconfig file and inserted [color] parameter as expected. 
This hasn't resolved the issue with applying modifications through `git apply`

Comment: [`git apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) takes **a patch** as the parameter, not a file to be patched.

Comment: Thanks. This was sufficient for me to find my way around.